# Algorithm to find fewest number of tags that encompass all items?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm thinking this might be NP-complete, but I'll ask anyway. Greedy algorithms don't seem to work in my head.

Given a set of items, each with 1 or more tags, I want to find the smallest set of tags that cover all the items.

**Edit:** See [my "solution" here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897893/how-to-optimize-this-suboptimal-set-cover-solution).

Comment: just for reference, the naive algorithm is n*2^k. just iterate over the power set of the tags and check that each tagged item is covered by the current set. n is the number of tagged items, k is the number of tags.

Comment: so... given 1000 items and 3000 tags... I'm looking at 1.2e906 operations... i.e., unsolvable... so much for that plan.

Comment: @Mark, for the most naive way to get optimal solution it's n*2^k. I'm not sure about better ways though. If you just want an approximation, it can probably be improved well beyond that.

Comment: weird...looks like this question got rolled back... I made a bunch of edits to it yesterday, but they're gone.

Comment: @Mark: If you know that some tags/subsets are bigger than others, you can greedily try solutions with those first, and skip untried solutions that must be composed of more sets than the best known solution. It's all about pruning, and depending on the distribution of tags, could be easy to solve quickly. Careful how you rank subsets of the conditional remaining set, though. The intersection operation needs to be fast.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That's exactly what I was doing, but it's still horrendously slow. Even just a greedy 1-pass sub-optimal solution becomes painfully slow with 10,000 items.

Comment: What @Potatoswatter said works best when there is a huge diversity in the number of tags -- some have a huge number, some have a middling number, some have few.   If they all have a similar # of tags (the max, say Nmax, isn't hugely bigger than the min), then you can just keep marching through so-far unincluded items and add all their tags   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Low-frequency_systems).  That will get you within a factor of Nmax of the optimal answer.    Note that this is just a hard problem, though, and its provable that any polynomial-time approximation isn't great.

Comment: @Jonathan: I was testing with a random number of tags, between 1 and 500. Would that be diverse enough? I don't quite understand that low-frequency solution.. why would we want to add *all* the sets which cover a particular element? Wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: @Mark - It sounds glib, but if you had a fast method for knowing which set was the right one to add, you wouldn't need an approximate algorithm.   Anyway, the right approximate method to use will depend a lot on the distribution of set memberships and set sizes in the real application.

Comment: @Mark: What do you mean by "random number of tags"? Don't test with fudged data…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Set Cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem, which is NP-complete.  Each tag defines a subset
of your list of items, and you want to find the minimum number of subsets (tags) whose union equals the full list of items.

Comment: Knew it'd have a name...just didn't know what it was called. Now I can investigate further, thanks :)